# Handle daylight savings time and representing UTC in Date object

Tags: java, spring, time

I have a function which returns the current UTC time in `Date` object, simple. What we do is find current `Instant` of UTC, put it in `Date` object and return. Note: Local Host time here is New York/America.

The problem we are now facing is that Date refuses to store *March 13 2:02 AM*, since the time doesn't exist (clocks skip an hour from 2 AM to 3 AM on second Sunday of March in NY), but the same exists in UTC, and we want UTC time.

Is there any way to represent `"20220313 02:02:00.000"` in java Date object.

This is when New York time(local) is `"20220312 21:02.00.000"`

```java
public static Date getCurrUtc() throws ParseException {
    Instant instant = Instant.now();
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneOffset.UTC);
    Date date = new Date();
    int year = ldt.getYear(),
        month = ldt.getMonthValue() - 1,
        day = ldt.getDayOfMonth(),
        hour = ldt.getHour(),
        minute = ldt.getMinute(),
        second = ldt.getSecond(),
        milliseconds = (int) date.getTime() % 1000;
    SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
    date = isoFormat.parse(String.format("%d-%d-%dT%d:%d:%d.%d", year, month, day, hour, minute, second, milliseconds));
    return date;
}
```

Comment: So you are trying to represent a UTC time in an outdated `Date` object holding the same wall-clock time (so a different moment) in America/New_York time zone? Sorry, that’s bad and confusing. It’s like having an `int` where the value 3 really means 8. Also your observation is correct: it is not always possible at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently mixing calls to two very different APIs (old and outdated `java.util.Date` and classes from `java.time`, like `LocalDateTime`). I would stick to the newer API because it makes life a lot easier if you want to express the same instant in two different time zones.

You can still use the `LocalDateTime` in order to parse the value from the `String` and then add a `ZoneId` to make it represent a real moment in time.

Here's an example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your example datetime String
    String datetime = "20220313 02:02:00.000";
    // a pattern representing the format of your datetime String
    String formatPattern = "uuuuMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS";
    // a formatter using that pattern (can parse and format)
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(formatPattern);
    // the two time zones involved
    ZoneId americaNewYork = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    ZoneId utc = ZoneId.of("UTC");
    // the date and time of day without any zone or offset
    LocalDateTime zonelessDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(datetime, dtf);
    // that date and time of day in New York
    ZonedDateTime newYorkTime = zonelessDateTime.atZone(americaNewYork);
    System.out.println(newYorkTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
    // the same instant in UTC (same date, different time of day, no offset
    ZonedDateTime utcTime = zonelessDateTime.atZone(utc);
    System.out.println(utcTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME));
}
```

As you can see in the output, the hours of day are different and so is the zone:

```
2022-03-13T03:02:00-04:00[America/New_York]
2022-03-13T02:02:00Z[UTC]
```

---

If you have to produce/consume `java.util.Date`s, you can make use of compatibility methods that have been implemented for reasons like yours: Dealing with a considerable large amount of legacy code.

Short: A `java.time.ZonedDateTime` and a `java.time.OffsetDateTime` are representations of *moments in time*, instants. Fortunately, there`s a` java.time.Instant`, too, and you can convert a` java.util.Date`from/to an`Instant`. There's` Date.from(Instant)`and`Date.toInstant()`. Here's how you would use the results of the code example above in order to have the values as` Date`:

```java
// convert the Instants represented by the ZonedDateTimes to Dates
Date newYorkDate = Date.from(newYorkTime.toInstant());
Date utcDate = Date.from(utcTime.toInstant());
// print the Date values
System.out.println(newYorkDate);
System.out.println(utcDate);
```

These lines would produce the following output:

```
Sun Mar 13 08:02:00 CET 2022
Sun Mar 13 03:02:00 CET 2022
```

**Please have a closer look at the values of the `java.util.Date`s.**
Zones implicitly changed **and** values adjusted (even though a `Date` does not really have a zone). You have basically no real control over zone shifts and time conversions.
There are several reasons for a totally new and different datetime API introduced in Java 8… The mentioned is just one of them.

---

### *Is there any way to represent "20220313 02:02:00.000" in java Date object?*

Yes, there is… You could create the `Date` and return it. *How* this `Date` instance will be represented as `String` depends on the `TimeZone` used. See this:

```java
// create the date
Date date = Date.from(
                LocalDateTime.parse("20220313 02:02:00.000", dtf)
                             .atZone(utc)
                             .toInstant()
            );
// get the milliseconds since 1970-01-01, the only numerical value stored by a Date
long epochMillis = date.getTime();
// create a format for visualization
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
// add a time zone to the format
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
// and use it to print the date in that zone
System.out.println(epochMillis + " in New York: " + isoFormat.format(date));
// set the time zone of the format to UTC
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
// and use it to print the date in a different zone
System.out.println(epochMillis + " in UTC:      " + isoFormat.format(date));
```

The output is the following, mind that the same `Date` is used:

```
1647136920000 in New York: 2022-03-12T21:02:00.000
1647136920000 in UTC:      2022-03-13T02:02:00.000
```

OK, the format is not stored in the `Date` variable, but the underlying value is, at least, which makes it representable in different formats that have different time zones.

Thing to think about:
Do you think the time zone should be part of the format rather than part of a datetime object itself? The answer to this question could be mapped to the question *Do you want to use `java.util.Date` or `java.time`?* ;-)

Comment: thanks you lots. This would be an ideal solution. But we have a big software here which makes use of this function at many places, so cannot abruptly change data types. Is there any way I can represent '20220313 02:02:00.000' in java Date object ?(we dont mind if timezone is different)  and without changing the default timezone of java.

Comment: @Wira Ok, I added some information about how to use my example **and** keep producing `java.util.Date`s ;-) Please note the values and make sure you really want to use this class. Better change the data now than in some arbitrary future, it will only get worse til then.

Comment: thank you @deHaar this is very informative, I can why we need to move to change out date representation object right away.

Comment: For the time being, I understand this is probably not possible, but if there is a way to represent '20220313 02:02:00.000' in java Date object while default timezone is Newyork, please let me know. We need to handle this case the coming sunday.

Comment: Well, the `Date` itself just stores epoch millis and a base calendar system. If one prints it, it will be printed in a readable format which requires involving several context related things *on the fly*, like using the time zone of the system wihtout explicitly telling/showing.

Comment: @Wira Please have a look at my latest edit of the answer.

Comment: Thank you lots @deHaar, time to deprecate util.Date now.